# Find distinct values in SQL when subquery returns more than one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

These are my tables

### **Table1**

- price
- city_category_id
- city_product_id

Here are three rows"

```
price | city_category_id | city_product_id
------+------------------+--------------------------
1500  | CHDELCLAPTOPDELL | CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR8
1200  | CHDELCLAPTOPDELL | CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR816
1000  | CHDELCLAPTOPDELL | CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR816
```

Here I have to find firstly distinct product_name and then select min price of the distinct elements.I want output as `CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR816 and 1200 and CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR816 and 1000`.

### **QUERY**

```
select min(price) 
from sellers_product 
where city_product_id=
(
   select distinct city_product_id 
   from sellers_product 
   where city_category_id='CHDELCLAPTOPDELL'
)
```

### **ERROR**

I know why this error is coming because there are more than 1 rows returned by subquery but is there any way to get the desired output using only 1 query.

Comment: change `city_product_id=` to `city_product_id IN (`

Comment: what's your rdbms? mysql or sql server?

Comment: why you have both mysql and mssql in tags?

Comment: @Abhik it is returning only 1 distinct price and city_product_id.I want two

Comment: remove distinct from the subquery then

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty But that is the problem I firstly want distinct ids and then out of these distinct is I want min price of each.

Comment: @Paolo because that's the way I code

Comment: @AK2 Now that you changed the data in the table the answer you provide is not correct; it selects the same product and two prices for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you want something like this:

```
DECLARE @sellers_product TABLE (price INT, Category_id VARCHAR(100), product_name VARCHAR(100))


INSERT INTO @sellers_product SELECT 1500, 'DELL', 'Vostro123'
INSERT INTO @sellers_product SELECT 1200, 'DELL', 'Vostro1234'
INSERT INTO @sellers_product SELECT 1000, 'DELL', 'Vostro123'



SELECT product_name, MIN(price) AS minPrice
FROM @sellers_product
WHERE Category_id = 'DELL'
GROUP BY product_name
```

Results:

```
product_name    minPrice
Vostro123       1000
Vostro1234      1200
```

This select first filters by `Category_id` for rows/categories, which you need, and then groups by 'product_name' to get unique name. In this case we group 2 rows with 'Vostro123' product_name. From this grouped rows we can also take `MIN` price value.

Comment: Thanks it worked.Just 1 last question could you explain me how this query worked.`
`SELECT product_name, MIN(price) AS minPrice
FROM @sellers_product
WHERE Category_id = 'DELL'
GROUP BY product_name`

Comment: I changed the @Darka solution to SQLITE and it gave the same answer that he had, so I gave him an extra point. NOTE: that DISTINCT is not needed/used, and only one SELECT is needed/used

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it is working. If your subquery returns more than one row then you cant use = as it will return single value:

```
select distinct city_product_id,min(price),product_name from sellers_product 
    where city_category_id='CHDELCLAPTOPDELL'
 Group By product_name
```

Comment: No ti didn't work.This `select min(price),city_product_id from sellers_product where city_product_id IN 
    (select distinct city_product_id from sellers_product 
    where city_category_id='CHDELCLAPTOPDELL')` returns only single row i want two rows with distinct ids and min price of these distinct ids

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE_RESULT AS 
(
    SELECT price, city_category_id, city_product_id, -- USE THE SELECT COLUMNS HERE
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city_product_id --USE THE DISTINCT COLUMN HERE 
    ORDER BY price ASC -- CHANGE THE ORDER HERE) ROW_NO
    FROM #TABLE1
)

SELECT price, city_category_id, city_product_id FROM CTE_RESULT 
WHERE ROW_NO=1 -- FILTERS THE DUPLICATE ROWS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
here is my answer using sqlite version 3 with your new data

.mode column
.separator ","
.header ON
.width 25 25

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sellers_product;

CREATE TABLE sellers_product (
    price             INT,
    city_category_id  VARCHAR(100),
    city_product_id   VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO sellers_product VALUES(1500, 'CHDELCLAPTOPDELL', 'CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR8');
INSERT INTO sellers_product VALUES(1200, 'CHDELCLAPTOPDELL', 'CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR816');
INSERT INTO sellers_product VALUES(1000, 'CHDELCLAPTOPDELL', 'CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR816');


SELECT city_product_id, MIN(price) AS minPrice
    FROM  sellers_product
    WHERE city_category_id = 'CHDELCLAPTOPDELL'
    GROUP BY city_product_id;


------------- output -----------------

city_product_id            minPrice
-------------------------  -------------------------
CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR8     1500
CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR816   1000
```